# MongoDB still works whether I'm running "mongod" or not

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman, backend

So I'm currently taking Mosh Hamedani's Nodejs course and I can't seem to disconnect from my MongoDB. While my program in Visual Studio Code is running using nodemon, I use "mongod" in my command prompt, then I use Postman to get my list of genre's and it works.
However I after using control + c in my command prompt for "mongod", it says it's "shut down", yet I can still get all my data on from my MongoDB using Postman. Clearly it's still connected in the backend, but how do I disconnect it?

I disconnected from my MongoDB compass and that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongod is a `daemon process`, it runs the background as a service, in order to stop the service you need to run

```
use admin
db.shutdownServer()
```

You need to run this command in `mongo shell`. Read more about [how to stop mongod process](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes).

Comment: Okay it worked! But how do I reconnect it? Because now I no longer have access to all the data I previously created such as genres, movies, ect.

Comment: Go to your installed folder, and in `bin` folder you will find `mongod` file, double click on it to re-run the service again, go to the link you will find all the info there